# Restoring deleted image to firebase using deleted image's URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, frontend, storage

I have react project which it's backend i built using express and as a database i'm using *mysql*. But for storing images i'm using *firebase storage*. basically when i click *file input* so on change it stores file to firebase storage immediately. Then it returns the url of that image and then i store that url to mysql database by clicking submit button in form.

My issue is when i want to update info and i again click that file input and then it deletes existed image from firebase storage and stores the new one. But i've not click submit button yet. If i want to click **cancel** button i want to restore that deleted previous image.

Is there any way to restore deleted file to firebase **in React**?